# cuda: involuntary memory changes during kernels

Tags: memory, cuda, kernel

im a beginer cuda programmer,

im trying to build an application similar to the Nvidia particle system example (many balls in a cube).

i have a kernel louncher function as below :

```
void Ccuda:: sort_Particles_And_Find_Cell_Start (int  *Cell_Start,          // output
                                                             int *Cell_End,                     // output
                                                             float3 *Sorted_Pos,                // output
                                                             float3 *Sorted_Vel,                //output
                                                             int  *Particle_Cell,                   // input
                                                             int  *Particle_Index,          // input
                                                             float3 *Old_Pos,
                                                             float3 *Old_Vel,
                                                             int   Num_Particles, 
                                                             int Num_Cells)
 {
     int numThreads, numBlocks;

     /*Cell_Start = (int*) cudaAlloc (Num_Cells, sizeof(int));
     Cell_End = (int*) cudaAlloc (Num_Cells, sizeof(int));
     Sorted_Pos = (float3*) cudaAlloc (Num_Particles, sizeof(int));
     Sorted_Vel = (float3*) cudaAlloc (Num_Particles, sizeof(int));*/

    int *h_p_cell = (int *) malloc (Num_Particles * sizeof (int));
    cudaMemcpy (h_p_cell,Particle_Cell, Num_Particles*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    free (h_p_cell);

    computeGridSize(Num_Particles, 512, numBlocks, numThreads);

    sort_Particles_And_Find_Cell_StartD<<<numBlocks, numThreads>>>(Cell_Start,Cell_End, Sorted_Pos, Sorted_Vel, Particle_Cell, Particle_Index, Old_Pos, Old_Vel, Num_Particles);

    h_p_cell = (int *) malloc (Num_Particles * sizeof (int));
    cudaMemcpy (h_p_cell,Particle_Cell, Num_Particles*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    free (h_p_cell);
 }
```

And this **global** kernel function :

```
__global__ void sort_Particles_And_Find_Cell_StartD(int  *Cell_Start,       // output
                                     int *Cell_End,                     // output
                                     float3 *Sorted_Pos,                // output
                                     float3 *Sorted_Vel,                //output
                                     int  *Particle_Cell,       // input
                                     int  *Particle_Index,          // input
                                     float3 *Old_Pos,
                                     float3 *Old_Vel,
                                     int   Num_Particles)
     {
        int hash;
        extern __shared__ int Shared_Hash[];    // blockSize + 1 elements
        int index = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

        if (index < Num_Particles)
        { 
             hash = Particle_Cell[index];
             Shared_Hash[threadIdx.x+1] = hash;

            if (index > 0 && threadIdx.x == 0)
            {
                // first thread in block load previous particle hash
                Shared_Hash[0] = Particle_Cell[index-1];
            }
        }

        __syncthreads();

    if (index < Num_Particles)
    {
        // If this particle has a different cell index to the previous
        // particle then it must be the first particle in the cell,
        // so store the index of this particle in the cell.
        // As it isn't the first particle, it must also be the cell end of
        // the previous particle's cell

        if (index == 0 || hash != Shared_Hash[threadIdx.x])     // if its the first thread in the grid or its particle cell index is different from cell index of the previous neighboring thread
        {
            Cell_Start[hash] = index;

            if (index > 0)
                Cell_End[Shared_Hash[threadIdx.x]] = index;
        }

        if (index == Num_Particles - 1)
        {
            Cell_End[hash] = index + 1;
        }

        // Now use the sorted index to reorder the pos and vel data
        int Sorted_Index = Particle_Index[index];
        //float3 pos = FETCH(Old_Pos, Sorted_Index);       // macro does either global read or texture fetch
        //float3 vel = FETCH(Old_Vel, Sorted_Index);       // see particles_kernel.cuh
        float3 pos = Old_Pos[Sorted_Index];
        float3 vel = Old_Vel[Sorted_Index];
        Sorted_Pos[index] = pos;
        Sorted_Vel[index] = vel;
    }
```

during execute i got this debug arror massege r6010 saying an abort has been called.

as you may see in the louncher function (the first one) i use int *h_p_cell to view
Particle_Cell content before and after the kernel execution, and it seems like the content has been changed, although inside the kernel there is no assignment to Particle_Cell.
Particle_Cell memory allocated by cudaMemcpy during program init().

i have trying for few days to solve this issue, without success
can anyone help ?

Comment: This question does not have enough information. There is no CUDA kernel to look at. You have not mentioned what the expected result is and what is the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel is expecting dynamically allocated [shared memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared):

```
    extern __shared__ int Shared_Hash[];    // blockSize + 1 elements
```

But you aren't allocating any in your kernel invocation:

```
sort_Particles_And_Find_Cell_StartD<<<numBlocks, numThreads>>>(Cell_Start,Cell_End, Sorted_Pos, Sorted_Vel, Particle_Cell, Particle_Index, Old_Pos, Old_Vel, Num_Particles);
                                                           ^
                                                           |
                                                missing shared memory size parameter
```

You should provide a shared memory amount in your [launch configuration](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#execution-configuration).  You probably want something like this:

```
sort_Particles_And_Find_Cell_StartD<<<numBlocks, numThreads, ((numThreads+1)*sizeof(int))>>>(Cell_Start,Cell_End, Sorted_Pos, Sorted_Vel, Particle_Cell, Particle_Index, Old_Pos, Old_Vel, Num_Particles);
```

This error will cause your kernel to abort when it tries to access shared memory.
You should also do [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on all cuda API calls and kernel calls. I don't see any evidence of that in your code.

Once you have all the API errors sorted out, run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.  The reason for the unexpected writes to `Particle_Cell` may be due to out-of-bounds accesses from your kernel, which will become evident with `cuda-memcheck`.

Comment: Hey, thanks alot!!! you realy helped me and its amazing how quickly. you made my day :)